# Compare the slope of a drawn line to $-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, gre-exam

You are given answer choices as follows:

A - if Quantity A will always be greater
  B - if Quantity B will always be greater
  C - if both quantities are equal
  D - if it can't be determined

[image: Figure]

I approached this question as follows.

We are given the point q for line m and we know it passes through the origin so i decided to use point q and o to find the slope.

$0-2/0-(-3) = -2/3$

Therefore the slope equals $-2/3$ which is greater then $-1$ and therefore the answer according to me is A. However the book suggests that answer is D.

Can anyone explain where i went wrong? The book is suggesting that since line m is steeper then $-2/3$  the quantity could be less then $ - 1 $ or greater then $ - 1 $. I don't get that explanation because I thought in order to find a slope you use two points on the line as I did earlier.

Comment: Point Q is not on line m. $\;$

Comment: The book assumes that the line perhaps does not have to pass through point Q. Doesn't make sense to me either, but then, the whoe GRE doesn't make too much sense to me. I helped a familiy member of mine with the GRE couple of years ago. Good luck!!

Comment: The diagram clearly shows that line $m$ does *not* pass through point $Q$.  This is not a subtle or tricky thing.

Comment: I thought it might be lying on the line because sometimes the diagrams are not drawn accurately or drawn to scale. if it is not lying on point q then it makes sense 100%.

Comment: No, you don't understand how the GRE works. The diagrams are *always* drawn accurately. If they could lie about something like whether $Q$ was on $m$, then you wouldn't be able to trust them about anything: you wouldn't be able to know that $m$ goes through $O$; you wouldn't be able to know that $m$ has a negative slope. It would be impossible to answer any question.  So you can always trust the appearance of the diagram. When they say it is not drawn accurately or to scale, they mean you shouldn't try to measure exact distances from the diagram when the distances aren't marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point $Q$ is not on line $m$.  So when you calculate the slope of the line from $Q$ to $O$, you don't get the slope of line $m$; you get the slope of a different line.  That's why answer $A$ is wrong.

The slope of the line $QO$ is $-\frac23$ as you said.  The slope of line $m$, which we call $A$, must be less than this. (That is, $A = \operatorname{slope}(m) < -\frac 23$.  But that is all you know.  $A$ could be -1; it could  be -2; it could be $-\frac45$.  So you don't know whether $A$ is greater than, equal to, or less than $-1$ from the information given.